# Is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I was creating a query, and somehow there seems to be a problem in my query.

Here is my query:

```
Select
E.last_name as [Last Name],
E.first_name as [First Name],
SUM(CASE WHEN empAttendance.status = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Absences],
SUM(CASE WHEN empAttendance.status = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Number of Lates]
from
empAttendance
INNER JOIN employee E ON empAttendance.emp_id = E.emp_id
WHERE E.company_id = (Select company_id from company Where company_name = @company)
```

Wherein the employee table has the emp_id column which is its PK and also the empAttendance has the emp_id as FK.

employee table has the `last_name` and the `first_name` columns.

The error says : `Column 'employee.last_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Believe it or not, the error message returned is both accurate, and a prescription for how to fix the error. It may cascade through a few iterations as you add columns to the GROUP BY one by one, but that is the price of experience.

Answer (score 4):

When using aggregate function `SUM` you need to `group by`:

```
Select
E.last_name as [Last Name],
E.first_name as [First Name],
SUM(CASE WHEN empAttendance.status = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Absences],
SUM(CASE WHEN empAttendance.status = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Number of Lates]
from
empAttendance
INNER JOIN employee E ON empAttendance.emp_id = E.emp_id
WHERE E.company_id = (Select company_id from company Where company_name = @company)
GROUP BY E.last_name, E.first_name
```